# Как достать данные из List python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ищу в active directory пользователя

```
import json
from ldap3 import Server, \
    Connection, \
    AUTO_BIND_NO_TLS, \
    SUBTREE, \
    ALL_ATTRIBUTES

def get_ldap_info(u):
    with Connection(Server('fpdc.office.local', port=636, use_ssl=True),
                    auto_bind=AUTO_BIND_NO_TLS,
                    read_only=True,
                    check_names=True,
                    user='office\\admin', password='password') as c:

        c.search(search_base='CN=Users,DC=office,DC=local',
                 search_filter='(&(samAccountName=' + u + '))',
                 search_scope=SUBTREE,
                 attributes=ALL_ATTRIBUTES,
                 get_operational_attributes=True)
    user = c.response
    print(user)

get_ldap_info('azarov')
```

Все ок находит, в ответ я получаю огромный list со слетевшей кодировкой в начале

```
[{'raw_attributes': {'objectCategory': [b'CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=office,DC=local'],
 'displayName': [b'\xd0\x90\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2 \xd0\x90\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb5\xd0\xba\xd1\x81\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb9 \xd0\xa1\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xb3\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb8\xd1\x87'], 
 'description': [b'\xd0\x9e\xd0\x9e\xd0\x9e "\xd0\xa4\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd1\x81-\xd0\x9f\xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd1\x82"'],
 'memberOf': [b'CN=1\xd0\xa3\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb9 \xd0\xb4\xd0\xbe\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd1\x83\xd0\xbf \xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe VPN,CN=Users,DC=office,DC=local'],
 'distinguishedName': [b'CN=\xd0\x90\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2 \xd0\x90\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb5\xd0\xba\xd1\x81\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb9 \xd0\xa1\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xb3\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb8\xd1\x87
 ,CN=Users,DC=office,DC=local'], 'uSNCreated': [b'9347027'], 'badPwdCount': [b'0'],
 'cn': [b'\xd0\x90\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2 \xd0\x90\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb5\xd0\xba\xd1\x81\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb9 \xd0\xa1\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xb3\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb8\xd1\x87'],
 'title': [b'-'], 'accountExpires': [b'9223372036854775807'], 'badPasswordTime': [b'131106217001926107'], 'sn': [b'\xd0\x90\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2'], 'countryCode': [b'0'], 
 'lastLogonTimestamp': [b'131124341221616362'], 'givenName': [b'\xd0\x90\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb5\xd0\xba\xd1\x81\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb9 \xd0\xa1\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xb3\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb8\xd1\x87'], 
 'sAMAccountName': [b'azarov'], 'pwdLastSet': [b'131106217305385000'], 'instanceType': [b'4'], 'whenCreated': [b'20150827103906.0Z'],
 'userPrincipalName': [b'azarov@office.local'], 'objectSid': [b'\x01\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x15\x00\x00\x00\x86v\x91\xbf\xc6V$\x16>\xb2\xee\xca{\x0c\x00\x00'],
 'objectGUID': [b'\xdd\xfa\x96_\xc0\xde\xeaL\x98G\x8b\xa9H$4\x1f'], 'whenChanged': [b'20160708071118.0Z'], 'codePage': [b'0'], 'objectClass': [b'top', b'person', b'organizationalPerson', b'user'], 
 'physicalDeliveryOfficeName': [b'\xd0\xa1\xd0\xba\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb4'], 'userAccountControl': [b'66048'], 'logonCount': [b'5'], 
 'company': [b'\xd0\x9e\xd0\x9e\xd0\x9e "\xd0\xa4\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd1\x81-\xd0\x9f\xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd1\x82"'], 
 'sAMAccountType': [b'805306368'], 'lockoutTime': [b'0'], 'department': [b'\xd0\xa1\xd0\xba\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb4'], 
 'name': [b'\xd0\x90\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2 \xd0\x90\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb5\xd0\xba\xd1\x81\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb9 \xd0\xa1\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xb3\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb8\xd1\x87'], 
 'uSNChanged': [b'12590824'], 'telephoneNumber': [b'-'], 'dSCorePropagationData': [b'20151030092151.0Z', b'20150827103853.0Z', b'16010101000001.0Z'], 'primaryGroupID': [b'513'], 
 'lastLogon': [b'131106217299896107']}, 'attributes': {'objectCategory': ['CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=office,DC=local'], 'displayName': ['Азаров Алексей Сергеевич'], 
 'description': ['ООО "Феникс-Презент"'], 'memberOf': ['CN=1Удаленный доступ по VPN,CN=Users,DC=office,DC=local'], 
 'distinguishedName': ['CN=Азаров Алексей Сергеевич,CN=Users,DC=office,DC=local'], 'uSNCreated': ['9347027'], 'badPwdCount': ['0'], 'cn': ['Азаров Алексей Сергеевич'], 
 'title': ['-'], 'accountExpires': ['9223372036854775807'], 'badPasswordTime': ['131106217001926107'], 'sn': ['Азаров'], 'countryCode': ['0'],
 'lastLogonTimestamp': ['131124341221616362'], 'givenName': ['Алексей Сергеевич'], 'sAMAccountName': ['azarov'], 'pwdLastSet': ['131106217305385000'], 'instanceType': ['4'],
 'whenCreated': ['20150827103906.0Z'], 'userPrincipalName': ['azarov@office.local'], 'objectSid': [b'\x01\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x15\x00\x00\x00\x86v\x91\xbf\xc6V$\x16>\xb2\xee\xca{\x0c\x00\x00'], 
 'objectGUID': [b'\xdd\xfa\x96_\xc0\xde\xeaL\x98G\x8b\xa9H$4\x1f'], 'whenChanged': ['20160708071118.0Z'], 
 'codePage': ['0'], 'objectClass': ['top', 'person', 'organizationalPerson', 'user'], 'physicalDeliveryOfficeName': ['Склад'], 'userAccountControl': ['66048'], 'logonCount': ['5'], 
 'company': ['ООО "Феникс-Презент"'], 'sAMAccountType': ['805306368'], 'lockoutTime': ['0'], 'department': ['Склад'], 'name': ['Азаров Алексей Сергеевич'],
 'uSNChanged': ['12590824'], 'telephoneNumber': ['-'], 'dSCorePropagationData': ['20151030092151.0Z', '20150827103853.0Z', '16010101000001.0Z'], 'primaryGroupID': ['513'],
 'lastLogon': ['131106217299896107']}, 'dn': 'CN=Азаров Алексей Сергеевич,CN=Users,DC=office,DC=local', 'type': 'searchResEntry'}]
```

как мне получить вот это `Азаров Алексей Сергеевич` и  может кто подскажет , как подровнять кодировку в ответе?

Comment: если `import` хочется на несколько строк разбить, то вместо слэша в конце строки, можно использовать скобки `from pkg import (mod1, mod2, mod3)` или повторить `from pkg` в начале каждой строки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Символ `b` в начале строк означает, что это байтовые строки. Python3 работает с unicode-строками. Чтобы преобразовать одно в другое используется функция [decode()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode)

```
ldap_info = get_ldap_info('azarov')
display_name = ldap_info[0]['raw_attributes']['displayName'][0]
print(display_name.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: выдает ошибку print(display_name.decode('utf-8'))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: Исправил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо все работает!

Comment: nitpick: 1- `b'` в начале строковых *констант* (literals) в исходном коде (в памяти никаких `b` префиксов нет) или в текстовом представлении (`repr()`) для bytes объектов 2- Python3 работает как с Unicode строками, так и байтами и другими объектами. Если входные данные текст, то конечно лучше в Юникод как можно быстрее преобразовать. Если входные данные двоичные (картинка например), то `.decode()` здесь не поможет.